# JARVIS type program that will not accept dicated text from speech recognition software

Tags: python, speech-recognition

A while back I wrote a program a bit like (movie) Iron Man's JARVIS that takes commands like "open a program" or "read text" and then does the appropriate actions. I've written it so that commands can be entered either via keyboard or speech recognition. The problem I'm having is that the program will not accept my dictated commands. If I type "Read text" it will follow the command. If I use speech recognition to enter "Read text" it calls "I DON'T UNDERSTAND". Keep in mind that the exact same text is being entered. Any help with this confounding issue is welcome and appreciated. Also, please forgive my old, messy code.

Here's code for the beginning up until the command portion:

```
import random
import time
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import webbrowser
import os
import sys
from sys import exit

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
POSITIVE_RESPONSES = ('good', 'great', 'fantastic', 'decent', 'fine', 'ok', 'okay')
NEGATIVE_RESPONSES = ('bad', 'terrible', 'sad', 'grumpy', 'angry', 'irritated', 'tired')
CONFIRMATION = ('yes', 'yeah', 'yep', 'yesh', 'sure', 'yeppers', 'yup')
DECLINATION = ('no', 'nope', 'too bad', 'nothing')
QUESTIONS = ('what', 'largest', 'ocean')
BROWSER = ('browser')
PROGRAM = ('program')
URL = ('url')
list1 = ['ccleaner', 'c++','minecraft','VLC', 'steam', 'guitar pro', 'dropbox', 'cbr reader', 'avast', 'paint.net' ]
list2 = ['Read text', 'Open a program', 'Open a browser', 'Open a URL', 'Converse']
NUM_SET_ONE = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
NUM_SET_TWO = (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
NUM_SET_THREE = (11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
NUM_SET_FOUR = (16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
NUM_SET_FIVE = (21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
NUM_SET_SIX = (26, 27, 28, 29, 30)

def opening():
    speaker.Speak('HELLO USER. WELCOME TO D UNDER MIFF LIN. I AM COMP YOO TRON, YOUR ANSWER TO EVERYTHING.')
    print('HELLO, USER. WELCOME TO DUNDER MIFFLIN. I AM COMPUTRON, YOUR ANSWER TO EVERYTHING.')

def reOpening():
    speaker.Speak('GOOD! THEN RE-START THE COVERSATION.')
    varResponse = str(input('GOOD! THEN RE-START THE COVERSATION.'))
    if varResponse in CONFIRMATION: ambiguousResponses()
    elif varResponse in DECLINATION: finalResponses()
    else: ambiguousResponses()

def browser():
    speaker.Speak('OPENING FIREFOX...')
    print('OPENING FIREFOX...')
    handle = webbrowser.get()
    handle.open('http://youtube.com')
    askAgain()

def url():
    speaker.Speak('ENTER YOUR U R L:')
    response = str(input('ENTER YOUR URL:'))
    handle = webbrowser.get()
    handle.open(response)
    askAgain()

def programs():
    speaker.Speak('ENTER THE PROGRAM\'S NAME:')
    response = str(input('ENTER THE PROGRAM\'S NAME:'))
    if response == list1[0]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING C CLEANER...')
        print('OPENING CCLEANER...')
        os.startfile("C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe")
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[1]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING C PLUS PLUS...')
        print('OPENING C++...')
        os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe")
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[2]:
        #speaker.Speak('OPENING WHY GEE OH PRO...')
        print('OPENING YGOPRO...')
        #os.startfile("C:\Users\Rj\Desktop\ygopro-1.030.0-V4-Percy-full")
        #askAgain()

    elif response == list1[3]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING VLC...')
        print('OPENING VLC...')
        os.startfile('C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe')
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[4]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING STEAM...')
        print('OPENING STEAM...')
        os.startfile('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe')
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[5]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING GUITAR PRO...')
        print('OPENING GUITAR PRO...')
        os.startfile('C:\Program Files (x86)\Guitar Pro 6\GuitarPro.exe')
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[6]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING DROP BOX...')
        print('OPENING DROP BOX...')
        # os.startfile()
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[7]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING CBR READER...')
        print('OPENING CBR READER...')
        os.startfile('C:\Program Files (x86)\CBR Reader\CBRReader.exe')
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[8]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING AVAST...')
        print('OPENING AVAST...')
        os.startfile('C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe')
        askAgain()
    elif response == list1[9]:
        speaker.Speak('OPENING PAINT.NET...')
        print('OPENING PAINT.NET...')
        # os.startfile()
        askAgain()
    else:
        speaker.Speak('I DON\'T UNDERSTAND')
        print('I DONT\'T UNDERSTAND')
        askAgain()

def askForQuestions():
    speaker.Speak('WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE ME TO DO? ENTER A COMMAND.')
    print('WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE ME TO DO? ENTER A COMMAND.')
    varResponse = str(input())
    if varResponse == list2[0]:
        readText()
    elif varResponse ==  list2[1]:
        programs()
    elif varResponse == list2[2]:
        browser()
    elif varResponse == list2[3]:
        url()
    elif varResponse == list2[4]:
        responseType()
    elif varResponse not in list2:
        misunderstanding()

def readText():
        print('ENTER YOUR TEXT: ')
        text = input()
        speaker.Speak(text)
        response = str(input('WOULD YOU LIKE TO ENTER MORE TEXT?'))
        if response == 'yes':
            readText()
        elif response == 'no':
            askAgain()
        else:
            print('I DON\'T UNDERSTAND, TRY AGAIN')
            readText()
```

Second test with smaller program:

```
import random
import time
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import webbrowser
import os
import sys
from sys import exit

speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

var1 = "Read text"
var2 = str(input("say something."))
if var2 == var1:
    print("Sucess!")
else:
    print("FAIL!!!")
```

Result with dictation:

```
>>> 
say something.Read text 
FAIL!!!
>>>
```

Result with keyboard:

```
>>> 
say something.Read text
Sucess!
>>>
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a smaller program? That way it is possible to identify the root cause :) (See http://sscce.org/ for more details)

Comment: Are you SURE it's understanding what you're saying as "read text"? Can you output what it actually thought it heard, so you can check? Maybe you're saying "read text" and the machine's hearing "rich test".

Comment: @ Magnus Hoff, I'll go ahead and do that. @ Renan, I'm 100% sure. The speech recognition software displays what it's going to enter. What it entered matched perfectly with what I typed.

Comment: have you considered case?

Comment: @ Joe, If you mean letter cases, yes. The "R" in "Read text" is capital in both the program and the input via speech recognition.

Comment: Second test for Magnus Hoff is in the edit.

Comment: Probably you might want to print values of var1 and var2 before you compare them or inspect the values with a debugger. There could be extra spaces or case issues. It's very unlikely speech recognition returns "Read text", most likely it returns "read text" and case is the issue. @Joe is right.

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar program in python i got round this by making the program listen for the word "Jarvis" as soon as the program heard this it would start listening. therefore "what time is it" wouldn't have a response but "Jarvis, what time is it" or "What time is it Jarvis" would have a response.